# After reinstalling and restoring my /home files, I can't use the volume indicator

Tags: pulseaudio

Some context: I just upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, or rather reinstalled it, because I formatted the partitions and I made a separated one for /home. I backed up /home, and after installing Precise, I copied the /home backup to its partition.

Now then. I've got sound and I can regulate the volume by typing 'alsamixer' in terminal, but, since my volume indicator didn't work, even after installing PulseAudio Volume Control, which said *Connection to PulseAudio failed. Automatic retry in 5s.*; Sound in System settings didn't show any hardware, and I don't have Privative Drivers to install, I took the risk of doing 'aptitude purge pulseaudio' - 'aptitude install pulseaudio'. Now I don't even have the useless volume indicator, and to adjust the volume I've got to keep typing 'alsamixer'.

When I type 'pulseaudio' in terminal, it gives me *E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory /home/USUARIO not ours.*

I commented about the /home backup because I also thought it could have been a settings file I shouldn't back up, but I don't know.

¿Any ideas?